# organize column with flex property

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout

http://jsfiddle.net/f8n9e/1/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-span-9" style="height:150px;">0</div>
    <div class="col col-span-3">1</div>
    <div class="col col-span-3">2</div>
    <div class="col col-span-3">3</div>
</div>
```

---

```
.row {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 1 8%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-span-3 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.col-span-9 {
  flex-basis: 75%;
}

.col {
  background-color: #999999;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

I have this code, but the result is not what i want. How can i achieve something like this example? I am only interested in css properties, without new html elements.

```
--------------------
|         |    1    |
|    0    |---------|
|         |    2    |
|         |---------|
|         |    3    |
--------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for can only be achieved using the column direction, which also requires a specified height.

http://jsfiddle.net/f8n9e/2/

```
.row {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 10em;
}
```

Otherwise you will have to add an extra element.  Also, Firefox does not support wrapping at all for Flexbox.